# How do i calculate the average value?

Tags: javascript

i'm a little bit stuck with the average function....
i want to calculate the average of the below variables

Diebstahl
Gewalt- und Tötungsdelikt
Diebstahl
Verbale Gewalt
Freiheitsberaubung
Sexualdelikt
Sachbeschädigung
Hausfriedensbruch
Hausfriedensbruch inkl. Diebstahl
Sachbeschädigung

```
// Dropdown Text selektieren - Straftatbestand
function selectStraftat() {
    var select = document.getElementById("ddStraftat");
    straftat = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
    ladeKarte();
}

function selectYear(value) {
    jahr = value;
    (document.getElementById("Year")).textContent = jahr;
    ladeKarte();
}

function ArrayAvg(wertediebstahl) {
    var i = 0, summ = 0, ArrayLen = wertediebstahl.length;
    while (i < ArrayLen) {
        summ = summ + wertediebstahl[i++];
}
    return summ / ArrayLen;
}

var a = ArrayAvg(wertediebstahl);
console.log(a)

// Asynch 
async function ladeKarte() {
    console.log(straftat, jahr)
    const karteSchweiz = await fetch(
        'https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/ch/ch-all.topo.json'
    ).then(response => response.json());

// Mit const wird eine Variable fixiert und durch das nicht mehr änderbar gemacht
    let ergebnis = [];
    DATA.forEach(d => {
        const objDelikt = d["Straftatbestand"];
        const objJahr = d["year"];
        const objKanton = d["Kanton"];
        const objWert = d["value"];

        if (objDelikt === straftat && objJahr === jahr) {
            ergebnis.push([objKanton, objWert]);
        }
    });
    // Die drei dots nehmen setzen einen Array -Datentyp- operator ein. Werte werden dabei umtransformiert und expanded. Bsp. Array 1,2,3 -> Transformation -> jeder eizelner Wert ist ein Argument.
    // Anstatt beliebige Anzahl bzw. in Min & Max. Spread operatro entpackt die einzelne Argument und setzt 
    let werte = DATA.map(d => d["value"]);
    let min = Math.min(...werte);
    let max = Math.max(...werte);

// Daten werden hier nach Straftatbestände gefiltert und ausgepsielt. Da es Strings sind, müssen sie in Zahlen umgewandelt werden -ParsInt- danach wird durch Map die Zahl umtransformiert. 
    let wertediebstahl = DATA.filter(d => d["Straftatbestand"] === "Gewalt- und Tötungsdelikt" && parseInt(d["year"]) <= parseInt(jahr)).map(d =>d["value"]);
    let diebstahl = DATA.filter(d => d["Straftatbestand"] === "Diebstahl" && parseInt(d["year"]) <= parseInt(jahr)).map(d =>d["value"]);
    let verbalegewalt = DATA.filter(d => d["Straftatbestand"] === "Verbale Gewalt" && parseInt(d["year"]) <= parseInt(jahr)).map(d =>d["value"]);
    let freiheitsberaubung = DATA.filter(d => d["Straftatbestand"] === "Freiheitsberaubung" && parseInt(d["year"]) <= parseInt(jahr)).map(d =>d["value"]);  
    let sexualdelikt = DATA.filter(d => d["Straftatbestand"] === "Sexualdelikt" && parseInt(d["year"]) <= parseInt(jahr)).map(d =>d["value"]);
    let sachbeaschadigung = DATA.filter(d => d["Straftatbestand"] === "Sachbeschädigung inkl. Diebstahl" && parseInt(d["year"]) <= parseInt(jahr)).map(d =>d["value"]);
    let hausfriedensbruch = DATA.filter(d => d["Straftatbestand"] === "Hausfriedensbruch" && parseInt(d["year"]) <= parseInt(jahr)).map(d =>d["value"]);  
    let hausfriedensbruch2 = DATA.filter(d => d["Straftatbestand"] === "Hausfriedensbruch inkl. Diebstahl" && parseInt(d["year"]) <= parseInt(jahr)).map(d =>d["value"]);
    let sachebschaedigung = DATA.filter(d => d["Straftatbestand"] === "Sachbeschädigung" && parseInt(d["year"]) <= parseInt(jahr)).map(d =>d["value"]);

   // let durchschnitt = wertediebstahl // durschnitt
    //html element definieren, element holen und ins HTML einfügen! 
    

    Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
        // Umrisskarte setzen
        title: {
            text: " "
        },
        chart: {
            map: karteSchweiz
        },
        // Farbgebung, dynamisch gesetzt anahnd min & max
        colorAxis: {
            min: min,
            max: max,
            minColor: '#FFFFFF',
            maxColor: '#622684'
        },
        // die eigentlichen Daten
        series: [{
            data: ergebnis,
            name: 'Anzahl',
            // Hover-Effekt
            states: {
                hover: {
                    color: '#622684'
                }
            },
            // Beschriftung der Daten
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}'
            }
        }]
    });

}
ladeKarte();
```

Thanks for your help! Much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Replace `myArray` with `wertediebstahl` in your code

Or if you want make your function with parameter

replace `ArrayAvg(wertediebstahl)` with `ArrayAvg(myArray)`

Comment: the myarray i replaced, but actually the variables i want to work with come from "let XY..." 
the error message says that "wertediebstahl" is not defined, but i actually defined it through "let XY.." ?

Comment: can you edit your question and write there full code or give the source of your code, cause when I run your code it says DATA is no defined

Comment: i added the whole code to the question. thanks for your help!